# “No package found” error when installing NGINX on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, nginx

The command `sudo yum install nginx` returns the error `No package nginx available`. I've tried this before and it worked but now it doesn't.

Please help!

Comment: Did you search for "nginx package centos 5" anywhere? What results did you get? Did you try the solutions they suggested? What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to add in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository, do this;

wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm {or whatever the filename is based on your version of Centos}
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm {or again whatever the filename is]

Then try the YUM again.

Comment: Thanks! My CentOS version is 5.8. I ran `rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm` and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the nginx repository as described on the [nginx.org site](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Official_Red_Hat.2FCentOS_packages).